# Circular list add and remove methods

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

How would I get my add and remove method, from normal linked, to circular linked list. Using this code, I presume I need a tail reference and so on?

```
 public void add(int index, Object item)
                  throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {


     //our index needs to go in along with our stuff in item
        Node temp = new Node(item);
        Node current = head;

        for(int i = 1; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        // set the new node's next-node reference to this node's next-node reference
        temp.setNext(current.getNext());
        // now set this node's next-node reference to the new node
        current.setNext(temp);
    //  current.setPrevious();
        numItems++;// increment the number of elements variable

  }  

  public boolean remove(int index) 
                   throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {

      if(index < 1 || index > size())
            return false;

        Node current = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(current.getNext() == null)
                return false;

            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        numItems--; // decrement the number of elements variable
        return true;


  }   // end remove
```

Answer (score 0):

In a circular linked list, `current.getNext()` will not be `null`. You will have to check when you reached the end of the list in another way (`current.getNext() == null` will always be `false`).

The first option is to compare with the head node, i.e. if `current.getNext() == head`, then `current` is the last element in the list and you can stop.

But since you're counting for the index anyway, you can also just make sure that the index will always be between 0 and `size()` (which you currently do in your remove method anyway).